# variable changing its value on its own in c

Tags: c, pointers, variables

For context, I'm a beginner in C and I was making a file with all the important details of the language, and I noticed that a variable (type `int`) that I defined in the start seemed to change its value later on in the program when I accessed it using pointers.

here's how the code goes on (I removed all the comments that explained each line(bc Im a beginner))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    printf("Hello World\n");

    int uninitialisedArrayOfInt[4];

    int initialisedArrayOfInt[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};


    int len = sizeof(uninitialisedArrayOfInt)/sizeof(int);


    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        uninitialisedArrayOfInt[i] = i+1;
        initialisedArrayOfInt[i] = i+2;
    }



    int i = 0;

    while(i<len){
        printf("%i\n", uninitialisedArrayOfInt[i]);
        i++;
    }


    int arr[1][1];


    char str1[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', '\0'}; 
    printf("%s\n", str1);

    char str2[] = "Hello World!";
    printf("%s\n", str2);


    int len2 = strlen(str1);
    printf("%i\n", len2);



    strcat(str1, str2); //the len values changes from this step to the next
    printf("%s\n", str1); //len becomes 1919899424


    char copycat[sizeof(str2)];
    strcpy(copycat, str2);
    printf("%s\n", copycat);



    int* lenPtr = &len;
    printf("%p\n", lenPtr);



    printf("%i\n", *lenPtr);
    *lenPtr = 200;
    printf("%i\n", len);

}
```

The funny part here is that I play around with `len` only in the start and end and yet the value changes to `1919899424`(it changes) on the line where I concatenate `str1` and `str2`.

Just so you guys know I ran this code in vscode and the compiler and debugger I am using is gcc and gdb.

**I had to include this entire code because without it the error does not occur**

as many are confused the `strcat()` function does not change the value of `len` as explained here ([https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-c-arrays-and-strings/lessons/strings-c/exercises/concatenating-strings#:~:text=What%20actually%20happens%20is%20the%20function%20takes%20the%20two%20strings%20and%20creates%20a%20char%20array%20of%20size%20strlen(src)%20%2B%20strlen(dst)%20%2B%201.](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-c-arrays-and-strings/lessons/strings-c/exercises/concatenating-strings#:%7E:text=What%20actually%20happens%20is%20the%20function%20takes%20the%20two%20strings%20and%20creates%20a%20char%20array%20of%20size%20strlen(src)%20%2B%20strlen(dst)%20%2B%201.))

Comment: `strcat(str1, str2);` - arrays are a fixed size (determined here by their initializers), and do not magically grow to accommodate more data. You are invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Comment: The definition `char str1[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', '\0'};` allocates *exactly* the right number of bytes to contain the data, and no more.

Comment: @Oka I am pretty sure that strcat() takes care of that by deleting ```str1``` and creating it again of size ```strlen(str1) + strlen(strr2) + 1``` as mentioned here (https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-c-arrays-and-strings/lessons/strings-c/exercises/concatenating-strings#:~:text=What%20actually%20happens%20is%20the%20function%20takes%20the%20two%20strings%20and%20creates%20a%20char%20array%20of%20size%20strlen(src)%20%2B%20strlen(dst)%20%2B%201.)

Comment: @WeatherVane I understand that but why does ```len``` change its value is my real question here

Comment: Because of the damage done by exceeding the allocated buffer. Anything might happen (it is unddefined) but that is what happened here.

Comment: But according to codecademy (the link shared) it shouldn't affect anything....

Comment: "by deleting str1 and creating it again" This is absolutely not what the link says. You cannot delete a variable and create another one of a different size in its place. This is not how C works.

Comment: Then use another tutorial if that's what it says (or leads you to believe). Note that your `1919899424` is `0x726F5720`, which contains ASCII letters `" Wor"` in reverse.

Comment: @n. m. Please do tell me if I am wrong but isnt it mentioned here?(https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-c-arrays-and-strings/lessons/strings-c/exercises/concatenating-strings#:~:text=Finally%2C%20it%20discards%20the%20memory%20occupied%20by%20the%20original%20dst%20string%20and%20associates%20the%20dst%20string%20variable%20with%20the%20new%20char%20array%20created.)

Comment: I'm sorry I was looking at a wrong place. Yes this is what this link says, and it is dead wrong. Stop using that site.

Comment: So to go along with the current explanation the function ```strcat()``` is an inadequate function to use, since it changes the value of other variables?

Comment: `strcat()` cannot change the size of an array variable. Nothing whatsoever can. It doesn't mean that `strcat()` is inadequate. Rather, it means that you misuse `strcat()` and that your array is inadequate. It should be of a sufficient size to contain what you want to put in it.

Comment: `strcat` like any other C string function does what is it supposed to do. When in doubt for a function of the standard library, you can have a look at the excellent [cppreference site](https://cppreference.com). Here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat explains that it adds the content of the source buffer to the end of the dst buffer  and explicitely says: *The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null character.*

Comment: yea I realized, thanks a lot

Comment: That tutorial, or at least the chapter you link, is complete and utter rubbish. I became a 5% worse programmer just by reading it.

Comment: The thing to realize is that Undefined Behavior is absolutely unpredictable.  It could crash your program, it could modify a variable, it could work just fine with no sign of trouble.  It could reformat your hard disk or make demons fly from your nose.  Avoid at all costs.

Comment: One more thing, when you see your program doing something impossible your first thought should be to try and find the Undefined Behavior.

Comment: It is good to stop reading this "academy" and read normal book for C.

Comment: thanks guys, yea I think I'll start finding a better source codecademy devs really messed up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no free space in `str1` to concat other string. After `concat` you modify memory outside of `str1` array and change the value of `len` variable (in this case).

Comment: as I said previously the```strcat()``` function takes care of that as mentioned here (https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-c-arrays-and-strings/lessons/strings-c/exercises/concatenating-strings#:~:text=What%20actually%20happens%20is%20the%20function%20takes%20the%20two%20strings%20and%20creates%20a%20char%20array%20of%20size%20strlen(src)%20%2B%20strlen(dst)%20%2B%201.)

Comment: But as mentioned here [strcat reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) its does not. Seems like you read a tutorial from someone who knows less C than you do. Happens all the time on the internet.  :-(

Comment: yea :(, I think I'll change my course.